# Page-Nav not working after set exclude tag query for CPT

Tags: wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

I created a Custom Post Type to set a library of fictions + documents on my site.
And then I want to hide the document genre from the post list by a little query to exclude slug "document" from my CPT archive page.

```
        <?php 
        /*exclude slug "document" from CPT*/
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => array( 'stfic' ),
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                'taxonomy' => 'stfic-genre',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => 'document',
                'operator' => 'NOT IN' 
                )
            )
        );

        $extquery = new WP_Query( $args );
        /*exclude slug "document" from CPT*/

        while( $extquery->have_posts() ): $extquery->the_post(); ?>
             //Do The stuff
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php umica_pagi() ?>
```

**but after that, my pagination below not working (added in functions.php):**

```
/*------------------Them Pagination-----------------*/
function umica_pagi() {

  if( is_singular() )
    return;

  global $wp_query;

  /** Stop execution if there's only 1 page */
  if( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )
    return;

  $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
  $max   = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );

  /** Add current page to the array */
  if ( $paged >= 1 )
    $links[] = $paged;

  /** Add the pages around the current page to the array */
  if ( $paged >= 3 ) {
    $links[] = $paged - 1;
    $links[] = $paged - 2;
  }

  if ( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {
    $links[] = $paged + 2;
    $links[] = $paged + 1;
  }

  echo '<div class="st3-pagi"><ul>' . "\n";

  /** Previous Post Link */
  if ( get_previous_posts_link() )
    printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_previous_posts_link('<i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Trang trước') );

  /** Link to first page, plus ellipses if necessary */
  if ( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {
    $class = 1 == $paged ? ' class="active"' : '';

    printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ), '1' );

    if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) )
      echo '<li>…</li>';
  }

  /** Link to current page, plus 2 pages in either direction if necessary */
  sort( $links );
  foreach ( (array) $links as $link ) {
    $class = $paged == $link ? ' class="active"' : '';
    printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $link ) ), $link );
  }

  /** Link to last page, plus ellipses if necessary */
  if ( ! in_array( $max, $links ) ) {
    if ( ! in_array( $max - 1, $links ) )
      echo '<li>…</li>' . "\n";

    $class = $paged == $max ? ' class="active"' : '';
    printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $max ) ), $max );
  }

  /** Next Post Link */
  if ( get_next_posts_link() )
    printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_next_posts_link('Trang Sau <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>') );

  echo '</ul></div>' . "\n";

}
```

**What did I do wrong?**

Comment: Do not use a custom query. Use `pre_get_posts` to remove the deisred term

Answer (score 0):

In your pagination function you use `global $wp_query` object to grab `max_num_pages` for pagination, but if you want to paginate your custom query, maybe this number is wrong?

I suggest you to modify your pagination function, if you want to paginate your custom query, to get one `max` parameter:

```php
    function umica_pagi( $max = false ) {
       ...
       if ( ! $max ) {
          $max = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );
       }
       ...  
    }
```

And then you can call your function like this:

```php
    <?php umica_pagi( $extquery->max_num_pages ); ?>
```

I had similar issue and this helps me then.

But if you want to paginate here not your custom query, but main query, you must call `wp_reset_postdata()` before calling pagination function, to restore global objects.